# Connecting database using MySQL connector

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse, android-emulator

I am a beginner to Android Eclipse. However, I have a project to do an Android application. I am unable to connect to the Android emulator using the MySQL connector to create a login page. Am I missing an important file?

Loginpage

```
package com.example.logininterface;

import com.example.logininterface.R.menu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtUserName;
    EditText txtPassword;
    Button btnLogin;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtUserName = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
        txtPassword = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
        btnLogin = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MySQLConn

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobiledb", "teddy", "password");

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from androidlogin");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next())
        {
            System.out.println(result.getString(1) + "" + result.getString(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any exception you facing ?

Comment: i believe that i am missing something in my codings. i can access myqsl database using java in eclipse. but not in the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think accessing any database directly from the Android layer is a good idea. It would be better if you could pass required parameters to a server page (PHP, JSP, etc.) and database connections could be done from server pages.

Coming to your question, `localhost` means Android in this case, so it will be looking for a MySQL database inside your emulator. Instead, you need to use your computer's IP address. Go to a terminal and type `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` if you are on *nix/Macintosh machine to get the IP address.

Comment: meaning i set up a php file to connect to mysql?

Comment: oh im sorry but im not quite clear about the computer's ip. will it be possible for you to elaborate on that?

Comment: @userVee open command prompt and type `ipconfig` and look for `IP Address` in the list. -- Also rolling back to revision 1, `10.0.0.X` is not the default IP for all, for some it will be `192.168.1.X`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use JSON with PHP to connect to the MySQL database. It is just an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It is better that you use JSON to communicate with the PHP script and within the PHP script to communicate with your localhost MySQL database. And you may try this to connect to your PHP script.

Example:

```
public class Login {

    ...
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://XXX.XXX.X.XX/Example/login.php";
    ...

    // Invoke by Intent activity by Login class
    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {

        ...
        protected void onPreExecute() {
          ....
        }

        protected Integer doInBackground() {
            ....
            // Getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                                                         params);
            ....
        }

        protected void onPostExecute() {
            ....
        }
    }
```

The **XXX.XXX.X.XX** is the local IP address of your computer, which means when your mobile is connected on the same network as your computer, the IP address is the computer local IP address. Do not put in localhost. **It won't work**.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "Localhost" use 10.0.2.2. Hope it helps!